# Pass a parameter to the ApplicationBarIconButton.Click

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, event-handling

*Hi everyone,
I'm new in WP7 dev. (i'm used to work on android) and there is a basic thing i don't know how to do. 
I create programmatically a list of ApplicationBarIconButton with this:

```
    for (int i=0; i<menus.Count(); i++)
{

  ApplicationBarIconButton button = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
  button.IconUri = new Uri(menus.ElementAt(i).Element("ImageUrl").Value.Trim(),UriKind.Relative);
   button.Text = menus.ElementAt(i).Element("Title").Value.Trim();
   button.Click += new EventHandler(button_clicked);
   ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(button);
}
```

and I want that the button_clicked method could retrieve the i value of the button.
How is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was beaten to it by @Enigmativity but his answer may still be incorrect. In my experience I've found that you need to clone the iterating `i` variable, otherwise on the click event, `i` will be the last value. If his doesn't work try this (again using a lamba function)

```
for (int i=0; i<menus.Count(); i++){
        ApplicationBarIconButton button = new ...
        ...
        var cloned = i;
        button.Click += (sender, e) => {
            sometTextBlock.Text = String.Format("App Button {0} pressed.", cloned);
        };
    }
```

Cheers,
Al.

Comment: Thanks for catching me out on that one. Felt foolish. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
for (int i=0; i<menus.Count(); i++)
{
    ApplicationBarIconButton button = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
    button.IconUri = new Uri(menus.ElementAt(i).Element("ImageUrl").Value.Trim(),UriKind.Relative);
    button.Text = menus.ElementAt(i).Element("Title").Value.Trim();
    var i2 = i; //Thanks to `ajmccall` - I forgot this.
    button.Click += (s, e) =>
    {
        // the variable `i2` is accessible now.
    };
    ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(button);
}
```

Rather than calling a method to handle click you can use a lambda and still get access to `i` (via local copy `i2`). You could then call any method passing `i2` as a parameter if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

An integrated way of achieving this is through the use of commanding in MVVM frameworks.
Granted with Application bar buttons / menu items it is a bit more tricky but far more flexible than to manipulate the UI Elements on the page.

Look in to MVVM light (http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com) or further with the likes of Calburn.Micro (http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/)

For application bar data binding you will need to google further (lost the link at the mo)